# JavaFx tablecell linked to more than one property

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecell

Hello I am new to JavaFX and when working with  tables cells I ran into some issue updating display data. I would like to be able to set up my table cells so that they listen to more than one value without having to initialized listeners in the update item method.

For example I have a bus class that contains three properties a string bus id a string street name and a movement bool. I currently have it setup with the bus id in column 1 and the current street in column 2 and would like to be able to set up such that if the bus is moving the street name is green and if stopped the street name is red. currently I have it set up that the setCellValueFactory for Column 2 is passed the street name property and in the updateItem method for those cells it  initializes a listener for the movement bool to update the color. While this current works it is hard to work with should I add more listeners to the cell, can I pass the cell more than one property during the setCellValueFactory method or another such method on the table columns to have the cell call the updateItem method for multiple events.

Comment: The way you describe is probably the canonical approach to this. Why is it hard to work with?

Comment: If that is the way to go about it then its fine to work with, it just seem strange to me that javafx has this very streamline approach to tables but I ended up just shoving some  listeners into the middle of it. Also it becomes more "complex" as you add more properties to work with and try and expand the same approach to different tables with different data types. I was just looking for an easy place to drop a group of properties in and let tableview do the rest and could not find much discussion about it online.

Comment: The other potential approach would be to define a very simple immutable class (or record, if you’re using Java 15+) encapsulating the street name and `moving` boolean. In the cell value factory return a binding wrapping an instance of that class which is bound to the two properties in the `Bus` class. Then your cell implementation doesn’t need any listeners; it’s `updateItem` method will be invoked any time either property changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a standard JavaFX model class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Bus {

    private final StringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty streetName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final BooleanProperty moving = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    
    public Bus(String id, String streetName, boolean moving) {
        setId(id);
        setStreetName(streetName);
        setMoving(moving);
    }
    
    
    public final StringProperty idProperty() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public final String getId() {
        return this.idProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setId(final String id) {
        this.idProperty().set(id);
    }
    
    public final StringProperty streetNameProperty() {
        return this.streetName;
    }
    
    public final String getStreetName() {
        return this.streetNameProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setStreetName(final String streetName) {
        this.streetNameProperty().set(streetName);
    }
    
    public final BooleanProperty movingProperty() {
        return this.moving;
    }
    
    public final boolean isMoving() {
        return this.movingProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setMoving(final boolean moving) {
        this.movingProperty().set(moving);
    }
    
}
```

the usual approach is the one you describe.  You can perhaps clean the code up a little by making the type of the column a `TableColumn<Bus, Bus>` and using bindings instead of listeners:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {
    
    private final String[] streets = {
            "Main Street",
            "Sunset Boulevard",
            "Electric Avenue",
            "Winding Road"
    };
    
    private final Random rng = new Random();
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Bus> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Bus, String> idCol = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty());
        
        TableColumn<Bus,  Bus> streetColumn = new TableColumn<>("Street");
        streetColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));
        
        
        
        streetColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Bus bus, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(bus, empty);
                
                textProperty().unbind();
                styleProperty().unbind();
                
                if (empty || bus == null) {
                    setText("");
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    textProperty().bind(bus.streetNameProperty());
                    styleProperty().bind(
                        Bindings.when(bus.movingProperty())
                            .then("-fx-text-fill: green;")
                            .otherwise("-fx-text-fill: red;")
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        table.getColumns().add(idCol);
        table.getColumns().add(streetColumn);
        

        // to check it works:
        TableColumn<Bus, Boolean> movingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Moving");
        movingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().movingProperty());
        table.getColumns().add(movingColumn);

        for (int busNumber = 1 ; busNumber <= 20 ; busNumber++) {
            table.getItems().add(createBus("Bus Number "+busNumber));
        }
        
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    // Create a Bus and a timeline 
    // that makes it start and stop and change streets at random:
    private Bus createBus(String id) {
        String street = streets[rng.nextInt(streets.length)];
        Bus bus = new Bus(id, street, true);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1 + rng.nextDouble()), 
                    event -> {
                        double choose = rng.nextDouble();
                        if (bus.isMoving() && choose < 0.25) {
                            bus.setStreetName(streets[rng.nextInt(streets.length)]);
                        } else {
                            if (choose < 0.5) {
                                bus.setMoving(! bus.isMoving());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return bus ;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Another approach is to define an immutable class (or `record`, if you are using Java 15 or later) encapsulating the street and whether or not the bus is moving. Then use a cell value factory that returns a binding which wraps an instance of that class and is bound to both the `streetNameProperty` and the `movingProperty`. The cell implementation will then be notified if either change, so no listeners or bindings are needed there:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    private final String[] streets = {
            "Main Street",
            "Sunset Boulevard",
            "Electric Avenue",
            "Winding Road"
    };

    private final Random rng = new Random();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Bus> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Bus, String> idCol = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty());

        TableColumn<Bus,  StreetMoving> streetColumn = new TableColumn<>("Street");
        streetColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Bus bus = cellData.getValue();
            return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                () -> new StreetMoving(bus.getStreetName(), bus.isMoving()), 
                bus.streetNameProperty(), 
                bus.movingProperty());
        });

        streetColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(StreetMoving street, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(street, empty);
                if (empty || street == null) {
                    setText("");
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    setText(street.street());
                    String color = street.moving() ? "green" : "red" ;
                    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + color + ";");
                }
            }
        });

        table.getColumns().add(idCol);
        table.getColumns().add(streetColumn);


        // to check it works:
        TableColumn<Bus, Boolean> movingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Moving");
        movingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().movingProperty());
        table.getColumns().add(movingColumn);

        for (int busNumber = 1 ; busNumber <= 20 ; busNumber++) {
            table.getItems().add(createBus("Bus Number "+busNumber));
        }


        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Bus createBus(String id) {
        String street = streets[rng.nextInt(streets.length)];
        Bus bus = new Bus(id, street, true);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1 + rng.nextDouble()), 
                    event -> {
                        double choose = rng.nextDouble();
                        if (bus.isMoving() && choose < 0.25) {
                            bus.setStreetName(streets[rng.nextInt(streets.length)]);
                        } else {
                            if (choose < 0.5) {
                                bus.setMoving(! bus.isMoving());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return bus ;
    }

    public static record StreetMoving(String street, boolean moving) {};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I generally prefer this second approach from a design perspective. Since the `streetColumn` changes its appearance when either the street or the moving properties change, it should be regarded as a view of both of those properties. Thus it makes sense to define a class representing the entity of which the column is a view; this is the role of the `StreetMoving` record. This is done externally to the model (`Bus`) so as not to "pollute" the model with details of the view. You can think of `StreetMoving` as playing the role of a Data Transfer Object (DTO) between the model and the view. The cell implementation is now very clean, because the `updateItem()` method receives exactly the data it is supposed to present (the street name and whether or not the bus is moving) and simply has to set graphical properties in response.

In real life I would probably implement the cell with a custom CSS `Pseudoclass` and toggle its value depending on the `moving` value; then delegate the actual choice of color to an external CSS file.

Comment: In the second version, do you even need to use `updateItem()` at all?  Couldn't you just have it all run off  bindings based on the `item` property of the cell?

Comment: @DaveB Yes. Though that's true for any cell implementation. You can always bind or register a listener with the `itemProperty()`, instead of overriding `updateItem(...)`. (Handling empty cells makes the bindings a little ugly.)